# Shape inheritance hierarchy

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance

I have managed to build an inheritance hierarchy for shape class object and I am wondering if there is a better solution to combine the following 2 hierarchies.

To begin, I have a 4 shapes classes triangle, line, oval and square which 3 of (line, oval and square) inherit from abstract class `SimpleTwoPointShape` and this abstract class with triangle class inherits from an abstract class `SimpleShape`. In addition triangle, oval and square classes implement `SimpleShapeAreaInterface` interface. The objects of the classes are created when there are enough points (x,y) to draw the shape (which is selected to draw at that time, as each shape has the necessary number of points to draw it). Points are putted on a canvas as my class where the drawings are being done extend `JPanel` and override `paintComponent`.

As the necessary number of points are putted on the canvas the shape is created with all the necessary details and is added to a List and repaint is called, which causes the `paintComponent` method to be called where inside a loop that loops through all shapes and depending on which kind of shape it is creates a corresponding wrapper class object (`triangleDrawer`, `lineDrawe`r, `ovalDrawer` and `squareDrawer`) which have the method to draw the shape. This 4 wrapper class inherit from an abstract class `SimpleDrawer` (has a `setColor` method) and the abstract class implements interface `ShapeDrawerInterface` which has the draw method.

```
private class MouseWatcher extends MouseAdapter {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // reset the rotation to 0 otherwise things get messy.
            currentRotation = 0;

            if (currentPoints == null) { // must be starting a new shape
                currentPoints = new ArrayList<>();
                Point firstPoint = new Point();
                firstPoint.x = e.getX();
                firstPoint.y = e.getY();
                currentPoints.add(firstPoint);
            } else {
                Point nextPoint = new Point();
                nextPoint.x = e.getX();
                nextPoint.y = e.getY();
                currentPoints.add(nextPoint);
                if (currentPoints.size() == shapeToDraw.getNumberOfPoints()) {
                    shapeToDraw.setVertices(currentPoints);
                    shapeToDraw.setColour(main.getCurrentColor());
                    shapeToDraw.setThickness(main.getCurrentThickness());
                    shapeToDraw.setShapeType(currentShapeType);
                    shapes.add(shapeToDraw);
                    setCurrentShapeType(currentShapeType);
                    currentPoints = null;
                }
            }
            //repaint(); // causes paintComponent() to be called
        }
    }

@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Graphics2D needed to set line thickness
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        Stroke s = g2d.getStroke(); // save stroke to restore later

        // rotate the drawing by the current rotation amount
        double rotateTheta;
        rotateTheta = currentRotation * Math.PI / 180;
        g2d.rotate(rotateTheta, this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);

        // Loop though the ArrayList drawing
        // all the shapes stored in it
        for(int i=0;i<shapes.size();i++){
            new ContextDrawing(drawingFactory.getDraweShape(shapes.get(i))).executeStrategy(g2d, currentBrightness);
        }

        g2d.setStroke(s);  // restore saved stroke
        if (currentPoints != null) { // draw dot where line started
            g2d.setColor(currentColor);
            for (int i = 0; i < currentPoints.size(); i++) {
                g2d.fillOval(currentPoints.get(i).x, currentPoints.get(i).y, 3, 3);
            }
        }
    }
```

The hierarchy so far for this is as fallows: 
[image: https://www.lucidchart.com/publicSegments/view/ef2ea6c4-14a6-4c5b-8b1d-69e8f3317b4d/image.png]

[image: Inheritance hierarchies]

Is there a better inheritance hierarchy to use for this classes? Are there any design patterns apart from factory that can apply here?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question.

Comment: A line is a non-area shape without volume/dimension. I would not wonder myself about a method like "getSurfaceSize()" on a shape **but** I would wonder myself about a the method on a line because it makes no sense for a line.

Comment: @PeterRader line does not have an "getArea" method unlike oval,square  and triangle. I think the class diagram with interface "SimpleShapeAreaInterface" depicts those classes which have it. Or I did not understand you correctly.

Comment: @PeterRader so in my case "SimpleShapeAreaInterface" is implemented  only by oval, triangle and square, not by line, but as I understand you, you mean it is a bad way to implement it on each single class if at least one class of the group does not have an area to return?

Comment: @vsarunov Sorry, I wrote it wrong: I mean `SimpleShapeTwoPointShape`. As long as "shape" is in the name, i expect a 2d-volume. This indicates that a SimpleLine indirectly also is a SimpleShape.

Comment: @PeterRader Well then if I change the name of the class it will be good? Or is a problem that Line is not a shape because it does not have an area thus cannot extend or implement the classes that point to a shape?

Comment: @vsarunov The design is good but the naming confuses me. Could you rename "SimpleShapeTwoPointShape" to "TwoPointForm" and "SimpleShape" to "SimpleForm"?

Comment: @PeterRader thank you will do, apart from that any ideas if there is a hierarchy that would combine the wrapper class logic with the shape logic?

Comment: @vsarunov I think you will not become complete answers because the code you posted is a little bit messy because a `MouseAdapter` ususally has no method paintComponent who could be overriden. To the design: you use paintComponent, so you are using swing, and you are forced to follow the MVC-Model of swing what indicates that the SimpleSquare is the Model and mostly mathematically, the Drawer looks like a Controller+View of the MVC and responsible for drawing multiple SimpleFigure-Instances with only one drawer-instance. If a Drawer is a Component there should only be one drawer for all figures

Comment: "Or is a problem that Line is not a shape because it does not have an area thus cannot extend or implement the classes that point to a shape?" If you want to have an abstract defined method "getArea()" and you are forced to implement this method in a concrete class although it does not make sense, then you are violating the Liskov Substitution Principle.